# What is a Native keyboard?

Tags: java-me, keyboard

I have a simple Java phone with touchscreen capabilities.In the 'Write Message' section a simple/normal keyboard(Non-Qwerty) is there to compose messages.Now my questions is, whether this default [simple/normal keyboard(Non-Qwerty)] is called Native Keyboard or it's something different altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a phone does not have a physical keyboard we call the virtual keyboard (shown on screen) as native keyboard.

If you use LCDUI Forms or TextBox this keyboard is presented automatically by the Java Virtual Machine.